# how to start/stop windows service using php

Tags: php, winapi, window

How I can start/stop windows service using php? I have found these functions:

```
win32_start_service('serviceName');
```

but it seems I have to include a class for winapi first, anybody can guide me plz?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

A brief solution is here [Stoping / Starting Windows 7 service from PHP script](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4702)

PS: You have to download and enable the extension as describe in above link.